# Fetch the Hazelcast Map values by index

Tags: java, hazelcast

How to fetch the hazelcast cache values by the position.

```
HazelcastInstance hazelCast = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
IMap<String, String> map = hazelCast.getMap("map1");
map.put("t1", "manu");
map.put("t2", "chite");
map.put("t3", "naveen");
map.put("t4", "vinoda");
```

My question is, Is there any method to fetch the values by the position

like

```
map.values().position(1)
```

output:-

```
chite
```

output:-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are different types of map implementation in Java, and what you want can be achieved with a LinkedHashMap or TreeMap, but IMap from Hazelcast does not support this. In fact the IMap is pretty different from a java Map.

> This class is not a general-purpose ConcurrentMap implementation! While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects. Instead of the equals method, this implementation compares the serialized byte version of the objects.
> Moreover, stored values are handled as having a value type semantics, while standard Java implementations treat them as having a reference type semantics.

Comment: Ordinality is pretty meaninglesss on such a map that is distrributed across multiple nodes, and where the data may be rearranged to balance the load. Insert sequence would perform badly -- to find the second oldest you have to scan all of them, as what is now second oldest may have been the third added if a predecessor was deleted.